# how to select second input box from cell using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the table with following structure . I am generating a dynamic table on the basis of input provided by user which will repeat this row .

I want to get the value of this text box and trying to use the code below

```js
if (row.getAttribute('val') === 'answer') {
  var Cell = table.rows[i].cells[0];
  alert(Cell.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<tr val='answer'>
  <td>
    <input type='checkbox' />
    <input style='width:483px' type='text' />
  </td>
</tr>
```

I am putting alert to check if i am getting the correct value .I can see the two inputs in the alert message I want to get the value of text box using javascript not jquery

Comment: `table.rows[i].cells[1].querySelector('input').value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to select all rows and then use loop to get only rows with `val='answer'` and then use `querySelector` to get input with `type="text"`

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  if (rows[i].getAttribute('val') == 'answer') {
    var input = rows[i].querySelector('input[type="text"]');
    console.log(input.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr val='answer'>
    <td>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <input value="Some value" style='width:483px' type='text' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```